# Remove space of TableLayout column

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm align 9 checkbox by TableLayout. I've align column by android:stretchColumns but the space between column are high. How to fix that space.

```
<TableLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:stretchColumns="1" >

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/cbRestaurant"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/drawer_select_restaurant"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/cbHotel"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/drawer_select_hotel"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/cbNightLife"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/drawer_select_nightlife"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/cbShopping"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/drawer_select_shopping"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/cbEmbrassies"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/drawer_select_embrassies"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/drawer_select_attaction"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/cbShopping1"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/drawer_select_hospital"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/cbEmbrassies1"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/drawer_select_bank"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="@string/drawer_select_police"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableLayout>
```

My current table
[image]

The result I want
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `android:layout_weight="1"` from each CheckBox and set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. That's confusing the TableRow. Then, set `android:stretchColumns="*"` instead of just 1. This will distribute the available width to all columns.

Comment: thanks for reply, but nothing changed. The space still exists

Comment: This helped me! All I had to do is remove the android:layout_weight="1" from the xml and it worked.